# ActiveMQ-CPP and Visual Studio 2003

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

ActiveMQ CPP and Visual Studio 2003

I've have a requirement to get AMQ to work with some code that requires VS 7.1, however I'm having a difficult time getting it and various Apache libraries like apr etc to build using VS 7.1. There is a vs2008 solution/project for AMQ-CPP, I've used that as a template and tried to create one for VS 7.1,

However when trying to build, I get errors like the following:

```
"\amq\activemq-cpp-library-3.4.1\src\main\activemq\util\primitivemap.cpp(70): fatal error C1001: INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR  (compiler file 'f:\vs70builds\3077\vc\Compiler\Utc\src\P2\main.c', line 148)"
```

In short has anyone been able to build and successfully run AMQ with VS 7.1? Is the compiler supported?

I've gone through the FAQ (found nothing to indicate one way or the other) and posted questions on their ML but to no avail.

Any info or links would be great.

http://activemq.apache.org/cms/index.html

Answer (score 5):

VS2003 is not supported, there are just to many C++ spec incompatibilities in that version to allow the code to compile.

Comment: Is there any plans to provide support at some point in the future?

Comment: Nope, VS2003 is just to bad at C++ spec compliance to waste the time on.